# Getting corrupted video stream when Reverse Engineering UDP video stream from cheap Indian WiFi camera Drone

Tags: android, networking, wireshark

[enter link description here](https://youtu.be/wbsQERiqhrE)

I have this Quadcopter "Garuda" that can stream video to an Android APP named VS FPV PRO over wifi.
I wanted to receive the video stream on my laptop to run some computer vision models so I tried to reverse engineer the Android APP using jadx decompiler.
I was able to write this python script that initiates the video stream and give a 1 second heartbeat packet to keep the video stream alive.
You can see that wireshark is receiving a steady flow of UDP packets of the video stream.
The command being

$ ffplay udp:/172.16.10.1:8888

I am using ffplay to display the video stream as internally in the app also ffmpeg was being used.
In the end of the above video you can see the stream I am able to see the top few lines are somewhat RGB and below it there is a lot of missing pixels. I suspect a decoding issue where error correction might not be happening. I tried setting the peobesize to 32, increasing fifo buggersize and setting framerate but the outcome was the same.
I feel I am close but I have no leads about this problem so please do give any suggestions or advice on what might be the problem and how to solve it.